# Switching between two UITabBarController?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

I'm developing storyboard based app and I'm wondering if I could have 2 TabBarControllers - one is for user not logged in and another one for user logged in. Can I swap NotLoggedInTabBarController to LoggedInTabBarController on login button action?

Answer (score 1):

If you add a Restoration ID to your viewControllers in the storyboard (identity inspector) you can instantiate a controller by calling the method `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:`

In your case, maybe i would have instantiate a parent view controller, and when wanting to swap of tabBarcontroller, I would have called

```
[parentViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabBarController2"];
```

And then change controller displayed.

(Not tested, just some ideas...)

Comment: added parent UINavigationController for my 2 TabBarControllers and tried your code on NavigationController viewDidAppera. Didn't worked

Answer (score 0):

You can add IBAction to your button with check of this condition and instantiate needed controller.

```
ViewController *viewController = nil;
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
YourViewController *viewController = nil;
if ([userManager isLoggedIn]) {
     viewController = (YourViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoggedInViewControllerIdentifier"];
} else {
     viewController = (YourViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NotLoggedInViewControllerIdentifier"];
}
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

in your storyboard you'll have to set storyboard id in Identity inspector

**EDIT**

If you are not using navigationController to route to correct logged/notlogged controllers then your could do sth like that:

```
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
[appDelegate.transitionController transitionToViewController:viewController
                                                 withOptions:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight];
```

Comment: viewControlled is managed by TabBarController which has no method pushViewController

Comment: what would be transitionController?

Comment: there has to be a viewcontroller that is presented (where you decide what to show next). Name it as you want - you have it and call transitionToViewController